# How to get document.referrer if condition for direct traffic

Tags: javascript

i use `ref = ('' + document.referrer + '');`to get referrer information in javascript. Sometimes this returns empty result. I want to have a condition which shows referrer information but if this returns empty result then Show referrer as **Direct Traffic**.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the current document was not opened through a link (for example, through a bookmark), an empty string is returned.

```js
ref ="Direct Traffic."

if(document.referrer){
ref = ('' + document.referrer + '');
}
console.log(ref);
```

Comment: i used this code var bhs = document.createElement('script');
   
    ref ="Direct Traffic."

if(document.referrer){
ref = ('' + document.referrer + '');
}
console.log(ref);
    var pn = window.location;
    var w_h = window.screen.width + " x " + window.screen.height;
    bhs.src = "//example.com/insert.php?site=" + bhs_id + "&r=" + ref + "&wh=" + w_h + "&pn=" + pn + "";    
    document.head.appendChild(bhs);

Comment: this return empty result

Comment: value of `ref` is not empty .maybe some other value in your code is empty